# Output value in the same input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use a function that converts a number to Roman numerals to display the converted value in the same box that it was inputted. [Like this converter](http://www.onlineconversion.com/roman_numerals_advanced.htm).

I've tried this:

**HTML**

```
<form name="f" onsubmit="this.box.value = convert(this.box.value); this.box.focus(); return false;">
    <input type="text" name="box" class="texty">
    <div style="padding-top:10px"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Convert">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    function convert(num) {
        var ara = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 6, 5, 4, 1];
        var rom = ['M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I'];
        var final = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < rom.length; i++) {
            while (num >= ara[i]) {
                final += rom[i];
                num -= ara[i];
            }
        }
        return final;
    } 
});
```

But it just refreshes the page and doesn't do anything to the inputted number...

[Here's the full code](http://codepen.io/l-emi/pen/pbQYAg) (sorry it's not a JSFiddle, couldn't get the form to work there).

Any help would be welcome, and thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to capture and prevent the submit event from happening, so the form doesn't submit, and the page reloads.

Right now your `convert()` function is out of scope, because the inline event handler is expecting it to be global, but wrapping it in `document.ready` makes it *not* global.

Easiest would be to use more jQuery, and remove the inline event handlers.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form[name="f"]').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var ara = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 6, 5, 4, 1];
    var rom = ['M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I'];
    var box = $(this).find('[name="box"]');
    var num = box.val();
    var final = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < rom.length; i++) {
      while (num >= ara[i]) {
        final += rom[i];
        num -= ara[i];
      }
    }

    box.val(final).focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="f">
  <input type="text" name="box" class="texty">
  <div style="padding-top:10px"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Convert">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're combining inline event handlers and jQuery handlers. Your `convert` function isn't in scope of the form because it's in the `$(document).ready()` block. I would recommend binding the handler using jQuery:

```
<form name="f">
    <input type="text" name="box" id="number" class="texty">
    <div style="padding-top:10px"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Convert">
</form>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('form').on(submit, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var num = $('#number').val();
        var ara = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 6, 5, 4, 1];
        var rom = ['M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I'];
        var final = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < rom.length; i++) {
            while (num >= ara[i]) {
                final += rom[i];
                num -= ara[i];
            }
        }
        $('#number').val(final);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use less inline javascript and let jQuery do all the job. You also don't need to use form, since you're not passing any data to any other script. You can just simply use input and button to do everything.

**see updated example >>** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXmwdR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#convert').click(function (){
    convert();
  });


    function convert() {
        var num = $('.texty').val();
        var ara = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 6, 5, 4, 1];
        var rom = ['M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I'];
        var final = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < rom.length; i++) {
            while (num >= ara[i]) {
                final += rom[i];
                num -= ara[i];
            }
        }
        $('.texty').val(final);
    }


});
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Simple + glad that form is out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: convert is not defined

The `convert` function is out of scope for your `onsubmit` event. This is throwing an error and halting the execution of the rest of your script so the `return false` never happens and the page refreshes.

You could declare `convert` on the global scope before using it

```
var convert;
$(document).ready(function () {
    convert = function(num)
```

Explicitly put it on the global scope in your ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.convert = function(num)
```

Or the preferred way attach your event listener un-obtrusevly in our document ready function so that convert is in scope.

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
  $("form").first().on("submit",function(){
    var box = document.getElementsByName("box")[0];
    box.value = convert(box.value);
    return false;
  });
  function convert(num) {
```